# how to get only not null element count in array php

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

i want to get only not null values count in that array , if i use `count()` or `sizeof` it will get the null indexes also .

in my case

i have an array like this `Array ( [0] => )`

the `count` is `1` . but i want to get the not null count , inthis case it should be `0` , how can i do this , please help............................

Comment: Only `NULL` or is `''` (empty string) and `FALSE` okay to remove as well (basically everything [`FALSE` in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php))?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

simply use array_filter() without callback

```
print_r(array_filter($entry));
```

Answer (score 15):

```
$count = count(array_filter($array));
```

[`array_filter`](http://php.net/array-filter) will remove any entries that evaluate to `false`, such as `null`, the number `0` and empty strings. If you want only `null` to be removed, you need:

```
$count = count(array_filter($array,create_function('$a','return $a !== null;')));
```

Answer (score 1):

something like...

```
$count=0;
foreach ($array as $k => $v)
{
    if (!empty($v))
    {
        $count++;
    }
}
```

should do the trick.
you could also wrap it in a function like:

```
function countArray($array)
{
$count=0;
foreach ($array as $k => $v)
{
    if (!empty($v))
    {
        $count++;
    }
}
return $count;

}

echo countArray($array);
```

Comment: You should be using isset not empty. empty will return true for false and 0

Answer (score 0):

One option is

```
echo "Count is ".count(array_filter($array_with_nulls, 'strlen'));
```

If you don't count empty and nulls values you can do this

```
echo "Count is ".count(array_filter($array_with_nulls));
```

In this blog you can see a little more info

http://briancray.com/2009/04/25/remove-null-values-php-arrays/

Answer (score 0):

```
// contact array
$contact_array = $_POST['arr'];

//remove empty values from array
$result_contact_array = array_filter($contact_array);
```