# How do I extract one value in array and leave the rest in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I need to get only one value in the array that is not null and dump. Bellow is an encoded array;

**Extraction**

```
$data = json_encode($request->get('amount'));
dd($data);
```

*Result**

```
"["196",null]"
```

**Now dumping**

```
dd($data[0]);
```

In short, this is what I want; I need to extract only **196** and leave the **null** value. I hope am clear enough.

Comment: `$request->get('amount')[0]`? Once you've encoded it to JSON it's just text, so it's too late

Comment: @ADyson but if the values interchange; i.e `"[null, "196"]"`

Comment: Are you trying to delete only null value from that array?

Comment: @Dominic see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7672562/how-to-get-only-not-null-element-count-in-array-php/7672599 for how to do that. My point was more about the fact you were trying to treat a JSON string like an array.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to get only not null element count in array php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7672562/how-to-get-only-not-null-element-count-in-array-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Collection

```
$data = collect($request->get('amount'))->filter()->toJson();
```

For int conversion - add map

```
$data = collect($request->get('amount'))->filter()->map(fn ($price) => (int) $price)->toJson()
```

Or, if you need exactly one value - change toJson() on first()

Comment: Thanks, I got this `"["196"]"` is there any way to remove special characters around the final result?

Comment: Do not use ```toJson()```. Use for example ```->first()``` it will return just ```196```. See my answer

Comment: @Andrian Zavis, Thanks a lot

Comment: Please note that my code was supposed to explain the problem step by step... Your code is just one-lined... It does not mean it is beautiful :)

Comment: This is really self-explained code - you comments does not say anything more than say code.

Answer (score 1):

You are using Laravel. There is good friend called 'collections', which is wrapper above php array.

Collections could help you easily out from your problem if you want to remove null value from array.

```
//Put encoded json to collection first
$data = collect($request->get('amount'));

//filter method without any parameters removes empty values.
$data->filter();

//In your collection is array contains ["196"]

//This would give you first argument which is "196"
$data->first();

//If you would like array
$data->toArray(); //put back to array
```

---

In one row:

```
$result = collect($request->get('amount'))->filter()->first(); 
//returns 196
```